# Como utilizar o Google Maps no Ionic para carregar várias localizações

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estou usando Ionic 1.3 e criando uma tela de Mapas,  essa tela contará com um menu para selecionar os destinos específicos e outra que é o mapas com a localização.

**Exemplo da tela de escolha de destinos:**

**Controller:**

```
var mapasJson = {
  "Foo": {
    "0": {
      "titulo": "local 1",
      "coordenadas": "001,002"
    },
    "1": {
      "titulo": "local 2",
      "coordenadas": "001,002"
    }
  }
};

app.controller('mapasItemsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $scope.destinos = mapasJson;
}]);
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="item item-divider">
  Foo
</div>
<div class="item item-button-right item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="d in destinos.Foo">
  {{d.titulo}}
  <a class="button button-positive" href="">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-navigate-outline"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dai minha dúvida é, como eu passo as coordenadas para a tag `<a>` para quando clicar nela chamar a tela do mapas e ai sim ir para a localização?

Aqui tem um demo do mapas: https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uzngt

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar como parametro para o controller da pagina que contem o mapa utilizando a diretiva ui-sref.

Ex:

```
<div class="item item-button-right item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="d in destinos.Foo">
  {{d.titulo}}
  <a class="button button-positive" ui-sref="mapa({latitude: d.latitude, longitude: d.longitude})">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-navigate-outline"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

E recuperar ele com o $stateParams.

```
app.controller('MapaCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
   var latitude = $stateParams.latitude;
}
```